Groovy bounded range isn't excluding the first value
According to Mr. Haki, Groovy 4 supports excluding the first value from a range construction. However, when I run the below Spock test, the first value printed is 0, not 1. What is going on here?
class RangeTest extends Specification {
    def "test range"() {
        expect:
        (0<..5).each {
            println it
        }
    }
}

This works just fine with plain Groovy, but fails in Spock.

It does not in a Groovy-Shell 4.0.21

I've discovered that. It seems it's something peculiar to what Spock is doing when it generates the class file.

Corresponding issue created by op https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1956 for cross reference
